# Adding a Custom View in Custom SurfaceView

Tags: android, view, surfaceview

I have a custom Surface View where I have drawn a background bitmap using threads, constructor and onDraw method, Here I need to add custom views into the surface view, is that possible if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SurfaceView` is *not* a `ViewGroup` it can't hold other views. You can draw your own though.

Comment: I am clear now. I will try some other way to attain that. If you come across any new way of achieving it please help me out.

Comment: @SriramCG other way is to get a `View` draw on our Canvas (the one we get from `SurfaceHolder`) from `onDraw()` of that `View`.